# How to wait for until buffer is complete to append serial data to file

Tags: c#, serial-port, buffer

I have some code that takes Serial Port data and both (1) displays it in a terminal window and (2) appends/writes the data to a time-stamped .txt file.

The problem is that while the data displays correctly in the terminal window within the C# application, the AppendToFile function will generate multiple files, i.e. chunks/packets that would have to be stitched together.

I've tried adding a conditional statement, looking for the last characters of the string (since they're known) but this doesn't work.

I've also tried Thread.Sleep, waiting ~3-4 seconds and this will instead of generating 4 files that need to be stitched together will create 2 files, one with the first few characters of the string and the second file with the rest/majority of the string.

Here is the AppendToFile function:

```
   private void AppendToFile(string toAppend)
    {
      string myFilePath = string.Format(@"C:\Battery_Report-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.txt", DateTime.Now);
      File.AppendAllText(myFilePath, toAppend);
    }
```

Here is the Data Received function w/out the conditional Statement:

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        // If the com port has been closed, do nothing
        if (!comport.IsOpen) 
  {
    return;
  }

  if (CurrentDataMode == DataMode.Text)
  {
    // Read all the data waiting in the buffer
    string data = comport.ReadExisting();

    if (data.Contains(" NOT ENTERED     "))
    {
        // Display the text to the user in the terminal
        Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, data);

        // Append data to text file and save it on the common drive
        AppendToFile(data);
    }
  }

}
```

Or w/out the if-statement:

```
if (CurrentDataMode == DataMode.Text)
  {
    // Read all the data waiting in the buffer
    string data = comport.ReadExisting();

        // Display the text to the user in the terminal
        Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, data);

        // Append data to text file and save it on the common drive
        AppendToFile(data);
  }
```

Again, the problem is that while the data displays correctly in the terminal window within the C# application, the AppendToFile function will generate multiple files, i.e. chunks/packets that should all be contained in a single file.

Figured out the solution, thanks to a colleague of mine and also jdweng:

```
  if (CurrentDataMode == DataMode.Text)
  {
      // Read all the data waiting in the buffer
      string data = comport.ReadExisting();
      var done = false;
            while (done == false)
            {
                data = data + comport.ReadExisting();
                if(data.Contains("NCR18650BF"))
                {

                    // Append data to text file and save it on the common drive
                    AppendToFile(data);
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            // Display the text to the user in the terminal
            Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, data);
            rtfTerminal.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to save `DateTime.Now` into a field, and then update it whenever you want a new file.

Comment: comport.ReadExisting(); only reads what is current available and not the entire message.  When sending data, the receive must know where the end of the file is located.  So the sending end MUST do one of following 1) ASCII : Terminate message with know character that is not part of the message 2) ASCII or binary : Include a byte count at beginning of message 3) ASCII or Binary : Send fixed size message.  Then modify you receive method to continue reading until all the data is received.

Comment: jdweng: the sending is something that I don't have control over. It is a CASP 2500 battery analyzer from the early 2000's that has a db25 connector, which is suppose to go to a serial dot-matrix printer. I have a db25-db9 converter that then connects to the computer and this serial monitor program just logs the data coming from the hardware. The format of this data is probably something I cannot change, i.e. probably embedded/firmware related, which would be proprietary to the company who manufactured the device.

Comment: Yeah, as Patrick already alluded to, `DateTime.Now` is always being _now_; in other words, the time at the moment of accessing `DateTime.Now`. So, with your current code, calling `AppendToFile` one second from _now_ will obviously create a different file path string `myFilePath` than if you were to call `AppendToFile` right _now_.

Comment: elgonzo: Yes, I understand that, but regardless of when the DateTime.Now is being called, the problem is higher-level per jdweng's suggestions. I fixed the problem. Look at my original post.